# Manipulate data from promise result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angular-services

```
var prom = $http.get('url');
prom.success(function(data){
  //here calling some service and updating the data 
});
$scope.abc = function(){
//doing some calculation with updated data
}
```

Once i get data from http request, i am calling some service which adds some info to received data. i.e data+service()=updatedData.
Now,on this updated data I am applying some calculation, and displaying it in view.
But this thing is not working. I tried to add this calculation to  **prom.success** itself, but still I am not getting updated data. I tried *setInterval()* to $scope.abc but some time it display sometime won't.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thank you

Comment: you have to perform some calculation and save it in `$scope.xyz` variable and again post that data

Answer (score 1):

Write a method in a service that will resolve the data. In the method first call $http to get the data. After it has got the data, call the 2nd service which will add extra info. Once that is done (i.e. the promise for the 2nd service has been resolved), resolve the update data. From the controller call this method in the service, and wait for it to be resoved. When it's resoved; 'then' call your method on scope that will display the data. I will post a working fiddle for you.

You can check the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pratikjs/HB7LU/24869/).

**Service**

```
myApp.factory('service', function($http, $q) {
  var addInfoToData = function(data) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    data.updatedInfo = "Some dummy info";
    deferred.resolve(data);
    return deferred.promise;
  };

  //Dummy Method for $http call
  var callApi = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var dummyData = {
      Id: 1,
      Name: "Fake Info",
      Value: 15
    };
    deferred.resolve(dummyData);
    return deferred.promise;
  }

  var getData = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    //Replace with $http
    callApi().then(function(data) {
      addInfoToData(data).then(function(updatedData) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
      })
    })
    return deferred.promise;
  }

  return {
    getData: getData
  }
})
```

Note: callApi method is a dummy method for $http call. Replace it with your actual API call.

**Controller**

```
function MyCtrl($scope, service) {
  $scope.name = 'Superhero';
  $scope.abc = function(data) {
    data.Value = data.Value / 100;
    $scope.displayData = data;
  }
  var getData = function() {
    service.getData().then(function(data) {
      $scope.abc(data);
    })
  }

  getData();
}
```

Comment: @user2827761 did it help? Or are you looking for something else?

Comment: thank you @Pratik Bhattacharya. Its works for me.
If I call another service instead of  data.updatedInfo = "Some dummy info"; to update data, then it gives error .. the service is undefined. I tried with dependency injection properly but still it gives an error.
any how thanks a lot.

Comment: I didn't get the issue. Can you elaborate a little. Are you trying to inject another service to make the http call?

Comment: Yes, I am injecting another service to make http call, and then adding the result to old data.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? I think there is some issue in the way you are injecting the service. If you share your code (fiddler or plunkr) I can try taking a look.

Comment: Hey Pratik , please go through the code, its not a exact code, but its efficient to know what actually i am doing.  Please let me know if m doing something wrong. Its showing 'service1' is undefined.

Please refer script.js file from plunker. 
Thank you
Plunk link [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/2WGi9u6rX8shUPDKX896?p=catalogue)

Comment: There seems to be some basic issues with your plunkr. AngularJS hasnt been referred and some of the parenthesis are in the wrong. I will try to fork it and create a working demo out of it.

Comment: I have updated the plunker, its working now but since i dont have any web services so the data is not coming from any real Http source. Here is the link - https://plnkr.co/edit/yPleIO81EPDVuEGY6jYo?p=preview. Tell me if it helps.

Comment: Hey prateek thanks for that. i just shown you what i am doing. Is it possible to call service in another service? the way i injected it, is that proper..
only problem in calling  the service i.e service2 . It shows "service2 is undefined" in-spite of  defining and declaring it.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Check the plunkr that I have provided, i am calling service1 from service2. I think you did not inject service1 properly in service2.

Comment: i have included the required things, please go through that and let me know.

here is the plunker link : [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/8jFXR5zBnEMbRO1PXv2N?p=preview)